# How can I go about fitting this not-quite-rectilinear data set to a rectilinear grid

Tags: algorithm, dataset

Consider this image:

[image]

I can (have!) written the code to locate each individual lilypad (i.e. those red squares, which aren't in the original image)

To a human, those individual lily pads form a very obvious 12 x 12 square grid, and it would be trivial to get a human to assign those pads into a 2D array of pads, at which point I can do any number of more interesting things with them.

But they aren't ACTUALLY in a nice grid. They're not rectilinear, they're not even uniformly offset.
How can I fit the pads (or equivalently, the top left corners of each square) onto a rectilinear grid. (Or what are the keywords necessary to find existing algorithms to do this)

---

Bonus 90s-kid-points for identifying the source ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the first square (any of them), give it a virtual coordinate `(0, 0)` and add this square to the queue. Then on each step, pop a square from the queue and try to find best top/bottom/left/right neighbors. For example, when finding a top neighbor we can minimize function equal to `|current.top - x.bottom| + |current.left - x.left|`. Then if this best neighbor square is not in the queue you add it to the queue with new coordinates `(current.x, current.y + 1)` and so on. If you get suspiciously large best distance - you are on the edge and you don't need to add a neighbor.

When the queue is empty you will get all squares with relative (to the chosen first square) coordinates and can transform them into the grid coordinates you need.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!